# AppDelegate class not found

Tags: ios, delegates, import, uiapplicationdelegate

I imported the AppDelegate.h in a lot of classes with:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AppDelegate *app;
```

but somehow it stopped working in my loginviewcontroller.h. It says:

```
 unknown type name 'AppDelegate' [1]
 property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type [3]
```

I made this class at the start and it always worked like it should. I didn't make any changes to the class or the `AppDelegate` when it starting with this error.

I can import it in other classes without problems. I also tried to recreate the class but it didn't help.

Anyone got any idea how to solve this weird error?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a circular dependency in your .h files? (Simplest way: #import "LoginViewController.h" in your AppDelegate.h). If so, you could use @class AppDelegate instead of the import here and do the import in your LoginViewController.m

Comment: i think this was the case indeed, i had an import of loginviewcontroller.h in my appdelegate.h and an appdelegate.h import in my loginviewcontroller.h.

moved the import of loginviewcontroller to the .m and in my loginviewcontroller i only call AppDelegate* appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] in the methods where i need it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use this line of code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AppDelegate *app;
```

in every class you need it. The simple way to access the delegate app where you need it is to do the following:

```
AppDelegate* appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

obviously you need to do:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

in the class where you use it.

If you want a cleaner way to do this, you can create a class method in your AppDelegate.h like the following:

```
+(AppDelegate*)sharedAppdelegate;
```

in AppDelegate.m is defined as follow:

```
+(AppDelegate*)sharedAppdelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Then, where you need it you could just call (after importing AppDelegate.h):

```
AppDelegate* sharedApp = [AppDelegate sharedAppdelegate];
```

Hope it helps.

**P.S.** Why do you need to access the delegate?

Comment: somehow it does work in the .m like you said.

need to be in the delegate so i can change from tabbarcontroller (have 2 and both are stored in the mainwindow).

Answer (score 1):

Declare a forward reference in .h file

```
@class AppDelegate

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{

}
```

// keep it as assign rather than retain to keep retainCount leveled for the variable

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) AppDelegate *app;
```

in .m file, grab the pointer to Appdelegate by importing AppDelegate.h and then assigning the variable

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   //use the variable.
}
```

Comment: have the same line of code in my viewdidload.
tried it with assign instead of retain but didn't help.

Comment: This line alone will work for you after importing AppDelegate.h file. AppDelegate* appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];//use appDel now

Comment: actually I don't see any reason for self.app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; not working for you. actually you are running AppDelegate.h file. AppDelegate* appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];//use appDel now, every-time you are getting a sharedInstance of AppDelegate and if you are loosing variable with (assign) type which means there is some problem with your code (memory related) which is corrupting your controller's data. You need to debug the same for this issue otherwise it will create problems for you later.

Comment: the line self.app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; worked, it was the line in the .h file that gave the problems.